# How do I create a higher order matrix from multiple matrices in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I am new to array matrices and I wanted help on a problem. Is there a way to do the following:

Lets say I have four 2x2 matrices - numpy arrays

[[A1 ,A2],[A3, A4]]

[[B1 ,B2],[B3, B4]]

[[C1 ,C2],[C3, C4]]

[[D1 ,D2],[D3, D4]]

Is there a way to get a 2x2x2x2 matrix that looks like

[ [[A1,B1],[C1,D1]] , [[A2,B2],[C2,D2]] , [[A3,B3],[C3,D3]] , [[A4,B4],[C4,D4]] ]

without using multiple for loops?

My intention is to create a large 2x2x2x2 matrix and do a dot product multiplication on the all the matrices in a given column.

I don't want to use multiple loops as in my use case I expect the number of columns in my individual matrix (A,B,C and D in this scenario) to be ~10000-20000 and rows ~500.

Edit with code: I think this works

```
    P=np.array([['P1','P2'],['P3','P4']])

    Q=np.array([['Q1','Q2'],['Q3','Q4']])

    R=np.array([['R1','R2'],['R3','R4']])

    S=np.array([['S1','S2'],['S3','S4']])

    X=np.stack((P,R),axis=-1)

    Y=np.stack((Q,S),axis=-1)

    np.stack((X,Y),axis=-1)

    result:

    array([[[['P1', 'Q1'],
     ['R1', 'S1']],

    [['P2', 'Q2'],
     ['R2', 'S2']]],


   [[['P3', 'Q3'],
     ['R3', 'S3']],

    [['P4', 'Q4'],
     ['R4', 'S4']]]], dtype='<U2')
```

Comment: What Python data structures are you using? I.e. lists, numpy arrays, etc.? Have you tried anything and seen whether it is actually a problem when you do use loops?

Comment: you may want to take a look at [numpy.stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) it seems like what you are looking for

Comment: Hi, you could just extend your matix to a list e.g. t = [], t.extend([A,B,C,D]), but from your question it is not clear at all what you want to do afterwards and why. Good luck :)

Comment: Nullman, thank you yes I think that is exactly what I was looking for. I've added what I have done in the edits

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly faster option:

```
>>> np.vstack((P,Q,R,S)).reshape(4,1,-1).T.reshape(2,2,2,2)
array([[[['P1', 'Q1'],
         ['R1', 'S1']],

        [['P2', 'Q2'],
         ['R2', 'S2']]],


       [[['P3', 'Q3'],
         ['R3', 'S3']],

        [['P4', 'Q4'],
         ['R4', 'S4']]]], dtype='<U2')
```

You first vertically stack your matrices, then you reshape them into sets of 4 unraveled elements, transpose to get the right combinations, and reshape again to the requested 2x2x2x2.

```
%timeit np.vstack((P,Q,R,S)).reshape(4,1,-1).T.reshape(2,2,2,2)
7.53 µs ± 102 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit op_method(P, Q, R, S)
20.5 µs ± 1.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```